# How do I move app icons between pages of the all-apps list?

Tags: user-interface, samsung-galaxy-note-8

My phone has four pages in its all-apps list (as opposed to its two pages of home screens). I know how to copy app icons from the all-apps list to any home screen. I also know how to move app icons within a single all-apps list page. (And while searching for answers to this question, I found how to remove blank home pages.)

What I haven't found is how to move icons from one page of the all-app list to another. To illustrate (simplified):

```
Home Page 1                      Home Page 2
 G         Say "OK Google"       T-Mobile             Visual
                                                     Voicemail
Phone  Messages  Play  Camera    Phone  Messages  Play  Camera

All Apps 1            All Apps 2            All Apps 3
A1  B1  C1  D1  E1    F1  G1  H1  I1  J1    K1  L1  M1  N1  O1
A2  B2  C2  D2  E2    E2  G2  H2  I2  J2    K2  L2  M2  N2  O2
A3  B3  C3  E3  E3    F3  G3  H3  I3  J3    K3  L3  M3  N3  O3
A4  B4  C4  D4  E4    F4  G4  H4  I4  J4    K4  L4  M4  N4  O4
A5  B5  C5  D5  E5    F5  G5  H5            K4  L5
A6  B6
```

If I want to copy app "H3" to the home screen, I just press and hold H3, and either wait until pop-up menu comes up with "Add to Home" as an option, or wait a moment longer so that the Home screen appears, and then movie it until I'm ready to drop it. That's easy.

If I want to move "N3" to the end of the All Apps 3 screen, I just long-push, drag the icon to the end of the screen, and release. It's there.

But, if I want to move "N3" to the end of All Apps 2, I don't know how to do it, and that's what I'm trying to find out.

--

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 8 with Android 8.0.0, kernel 4.4.78-14375742, but I've seen the same issue on my previous phone, a Samsung Galaxy Note 3 with Android 5.0, so it seems to be a version-independent issue.

Comment: I just tried this on my Galaxy Note 8 and it's working. I can drag apps from one app screen to the next by dragging them close to the edge of the screen, just like I would on the home screen.  Just have to make sure the app screen sort setting is set to "custom", but you must have already done that if you can move them at all.

Comment: I tried again, and it looks like it's a picky maneuver; it only works if the first step of the drag is up or down. Maybe with more experiments I can find a more detailed explanation.